# Serialize JSON with numbers as property names

Tags: c#, json, serialization

How can I serialize a `DataTable` which contains a list of phone numbers, `BodyOverride` and `ChannelType` to this structure? The final JSON should look like the sample below.  I see some posts that suggest using a Dictionary, but not I'm not sure if I can achieve this.

```
{
  "Addresses": {
    "+1713XXXXXXX": {
      "BodyOverride": "sent",
      "ChannelType": "SMS"
    },
    "+1832XXXXXXX": {
      "BodyOverride": "this is a text from PINPOINT",
      "ChannelType": "SMS"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: whats wrong with dictionary?

Comment: Dictionary will work.  See [How can I parse a JSON string that would cause illegal C# identifiers?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24536564/3744182) or [Create a strongly typed c# object from json object with ID as the name](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34213724/3744182) or [Deserialize nested JSON into C# objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38793151/3744182) or [JSON .NET deserialize into complex type with object key/name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26141320) or etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try a using class structure like this:

```
public class Payload
{
    public Dictionary<string, Item> Addresses { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string BodyOverride { get; set; }
    public string ChannelType { get; set; }
}
```

Assuming you are starting from a `DataTable` that looks like this:

```
DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
dataTable.Columns.Add("Address");
dataTable.Columns.Add("BodyOverride");
dataTable.Columns.Add("ChannelType");
dataTable.Rows.Add("+1713XXXXXXX", "sent", "SMS");
dataTable.Rows.Add("+1832XXXXXXX", "this is a text from PINPOINT", "SMS");
```

...you can easily convert it to the desired class structure like this:

```
var payload = new Payload
{
    Addresses = dataTable.Rows
        .Cast<DataRow>()
        .ToDictionary(row => (string)row["Address"],
                      row => new Item
                      {
                          BodyOverride = (string)row["BodyOverride"],
                          ChannelType = (string)row["ChannelType"]
                      })
};
```

...and finally serialize it to JSON using a decent serialization library like [Json.Net](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json):

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(payload, Formatting.Indented);
```

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/b7Ckzs

**Important note**: the above solution assumes that the phone numbers in the `Address` column will be distinct across all rows in the `DataTable`.  If they are not, then this solution *will not work*, because dictionary keys are required to be unique.  In that case you will need to split the data into multiple batches, or find some other solution to deal with duplicates.

Comment: Thank you very much Brian. This is extremely helpful. I never use Dictionary before so it's hard to me to figure out how to load it