# C# property value as Json Key Name

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have Json like this:

```
  {
  "Result": {
    "Bruce": {
      "City": "Gotham",
      "Age": 43
    },
    "Clark": {
      "City": "Metro",
      "Age": 43
    }
  }
}
```

When I deserialize it, I need the following class structure

```
    public class Clark
    {
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    public class Bruce
    {
        public string City { get; set; }
        public int Age { get; set; }
    }

    public class Result
    {
        public Bruce Bruce { get; set; }
        public Clark Clark { get; set; }

    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Result Result { get; set; }
    }
```

That means I need to create specific classes as **Bruce**,**Clark** etc. Is it possible to deserialize this Json where instead of seperate Bruce, Clark etc, I have just one Person Class like this

```
    public class Person
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }

        public int Age { get; set; }
    }
    public class Result
    {           
        public List<Person> Persons { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public Result Result { get; set; }
    }
```

so that the JSON becomes like :

```
{
  "Result": {
    "Persons": [
      {
        "Name": "Bruce",
        "City": "Gotham",
        "Age": 43
      },
      {
        "Name": "Clark",
        "City": "Metro",
        "Age": 43
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: `Result` should be a `Dictionary<string, Person>`, thats literally all you have to do.  Just iterate through the values of the Dictionary after serialization

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: @cyboashu if thats what you want, then check my comment

Comment: @maccettura, `Dictionary<string,Person> Result { get; set; }` worked. thanks for the response. Could you please add that as an answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JSON .NET deserialize into complex type with object key/name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26141320/json-net-deserialize-into-complex-type-with-object-key-name)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Json describes an object with a single property called `Result`, that is a `Dictionary<string, Person>`.

So your class(es) just need to look like is:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Dictionary<string, Person> Result { get; set; }
}
```